# Как сделать replace ограниченное число раз?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, replace

Как я могу сделать только 1 замену в строке, которая совпадает с шаблоном несколько раз? Первое, что приходит на ум - это регулярки. Однако шаблон вбивает юзер-> регулярку можно поломать из-за спецсимволов. Можно ли сделать так, что бы все спец символы интрпритировалисъ, как обычные символы? Есть у меня решение в лоб в последовательной замены спецсимволов на экранированным эквиваленты, но нельзя это сделать иначе?  Есть ли в c# еще что-нибудь, что поможет мне решить данную задачу без создания собственной функции? В vba, к примеру, можно задавать дополнительные параметры в виде количества замен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строку можно заэскейпить вызовом [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Он корректно экранирует все спецсимволы.

После этого использовать перегрузку `Regex.Replace`, [которая принимает максимальное количество замен](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/haekbhys(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(stringToReplace));
regex.Replace(input, replacement, 1);
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!